# Adding attributes to Q_PROPERTYs

Tags: qt

I'm making use of [Q_PROPERTY](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/properties.html)s in my project, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to add some attributes to those properties ([like min and max value](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtpropertybrowser/qtvariantpropertymanager.html#details)).

It doesn't look like there's any where to store such attributes on the property itself... so I guess I have to store it on the object... statically, since the ranges will be the same for all instances of that class.

Looks like I may need a triplet, `<propertyName, attributeName, value>`.

What should I do? Use a `QMap<QString, QVariant>` and collapse the first two to "propertyName/attributeName"? If so, where would you initialize this map?

Comment: Maybe I can abuse QMetaClassInfo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have the property and other properties to describe the min/max values. It is straightforward and easy to understand and use- which to me is a plus.

Comment: Have a property to describe another property? I could do it.... but it doesn't seem very elegant. Oh well..